# Set value in app.config - no write access to Program Files

Tags: c#, .net, app-config

I would like to change values in my `app.config` file (or rather `MyProgramName.config` file) at runtime. This works fine using

```
System.Configuration.Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
//update values in config.AppSettings...
config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
```

However the `MyProgramName.config` file is *always* stored in the program folder according to the documentation (https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.configuration.configurationuserlevel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Application configuration files are in the same directory as the application and have the same name, but with a .config extension. For example, the configuration file for C:\System\Public.exe is C:\System\Public.exe.config.

Now lets assume I have some users who can not write to `C:\Program Files(x86)\...` (which is the default setting for non-admin users on win7). Is there a way to still use the app.config file properly or maybe place it in the %APPDATA% folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the User settings capability of the application settings api for this. These settings are stored in `%userprofile%\appdata\local` or `%userprofile%\Local Settings\Application Data` (windows version dependent).

User settings has some limitations: it is, as it says, user specific not global for all users - but presumably if you are updating values at runtime then that's what you want, otherwise you need something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5931796/1945631).

You essentially just have to add a .settings file, which creates the `applicationSettings` and/or `userSettings` sections in your app.config (see [MSDN: How To: Create a New Setting at Design Time](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397757(v=vs.110).aspx)), create your property and set it to `User`, not `Application`, and then do this at runtime:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.myColor = Color.AliceBlue;
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

The .settings property will create a user settings entry in your app.config that looks like this:

```xml
<setting name="Setting1" serializeAs="String" >
 <value>My Setting Value</value>
</setting>
```

You can use this to set the default value that a user session will get before any user-specific value has been saved.

Reference: [MSDN: Using Application Settings and User Settings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397750(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Data, stored in `app.config`, are not intended for changing by regular user at run-time. Do not write a code, which re-writes `app.config`, except the case, when this code is located at some config application for admin. Use application settings instead.